# SQL Server Reporting Services in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2012-datatools

I have existing installation of SQL Server 2008 R2. I need to add SQL Server Reporting Services. When I install the feature then I select 2nd option which shows to add feature in existing installation when I select second option

[image]

when I install it shows me an error - how can I resolve this and how do I install successfully?

[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is supported in evaluate version and not express.

Comment: this is not express this is SQL SERVER 2008 R2

Comment: This is SQL SERVER 2008 R2 Express Edition.

Comment: @user2931015: the first of your screenshots **clearly** shows `Express` in the `Edition` column .....

Comment: oh sorry i posted wrong screen shot ...buy the way i have sql server 2008 r2